# Using relative positioning and margins is a bad practise?

Tags: css

I made something with my limited css knowledge. Here it is.

http://cssdesk.com/jEh8f

Final product should be similar to this.
http://www.solomid.net/guides.php?g=15768-paintballreturns-fya-umashi-jax-build-guide
(Masteries section)

I did the positioning with relative and margins. Is this a bad practise? Can it be done better?

Every single box has the following css, so I believe something could be done alot better/more simplified.

```
    #box-1 {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    width: 56px;
    height: 56px;
    background-image:url('http://www.solomid.net/guide/masteries/511.png');top center no-repeat;
    margin-top: 15px;
    margin-left: 5%;
    }
```

Ps. By the way, for such styling experiences, is there any tutorials/guides on web you can suggest?

Answer (score 0):

I would actually call this the preferred practice. I tend to avoid absolute positioning at all costs unless these simply is no other option. I just don't care for the issues it presents cross-browser. Margin is incredibly useful.

In terms of CSS tutorials, I like to refer to Google's Recommended Style Guide:
http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/htmlcssguide.xml